# Presenting users their API Keys on frontend

Tags: encryption, web-application, account-security, api, storage

I'm not talking about showing them a popup *upon api key generation*, where the user is specifically warned about the fact that

> This is the only time you will see it. Make sure to save this to a safe place.

Instead, I'm talking about platforms, like RapidApi, where the ApiKey is automatically filled-in for each Api in the platform, whether the user is subscribed to an Api or not.
[image]
(example from RapidApi)

Putting aside the fact that on RapidApi you can even use just a single ApiKey for each subscribed Api, instead of generating a new and unique ApiKey for a specific Api, how do they do that?
If the frontend is able to fill automatically the `X-RapidApi-Key` field, (I suppose) it means that the frontend is asking their backend what is my ApiKey.
Also that means that the ApiKey itself could not be hashed in their databases, but *at least* it is encrypted and decrypted upon demand.
Eventually I suppose they are encrypting the API on the backend and sending it to the frontend, which is then decrypting it with a public key?
Alternatively it is just plain text in their database or I'm missing something.
On other API platforms, the ApiKey is exposed only upon generation and it is up to the user to save it and use it. Which is pretty much secure, but of course it's not that handy if a user is able to use multiple API/ApiKeys.